# Can you soak clams in a salt water pool for a couple of hours

Tags: clams

We changed over to a salt water pool this year. Can we soak clams for a couple of hours in the pool before we serve them?

Answer (score 4):

The vast majority of purchased clams have already been purged, so this might not be necessary at all.  However, if it is...as far as I can tell, on average a salt water pool is abut 10 times less salty than the ocean. Correct salinity is important so as not to kill the clams. You also need to consider the temperature.  [This article is helpful](https://honest-food.net/how-to-purge-sand-from-clams/), and describes the purging of clams.  He uses seawater, or approximates it with 35 grams of salt dissolved in each 1000 grams of water. He also discusses temperature ranges and the need to avoid "shocking" the clams when soaking. If it were me, I probably would not use the pool, but rather, use seawater or approximated sea water and be sure to consider time and temperature.